# How do I transfer what I want from the Inspect Element to the CSS panel?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to change this Div to increase the margin-bottom to 15px. I've done it in the Inspect element, but I have no idea how to make it change on the wordpress site I'm working on.

Here is the Div and the styles in the inspect element. As you can see I've already set margin-bottom to 15px. I guess the problem I'm having is I'm not sure what to call (The div or the class) and I dont know how to.

I've tried `.vc_column-inner vc_custom_1453133443161{style}` and `#vc_column-inner vc_custom_1453133443161{style}` but neither worked.

```css
media="all"
#site #content div > :last-child, #site #content aside > :last-child, #site #content article > :last-child, #site #content div > p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1453133443161">
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just change it within visual composer?

Comment: is it possible to use the two applied classes or are they dynamic? `.vc_column-inner.vc_custom_1453133443161 {margin-bottom: 15px;}`

Comment: I don't see the option too but thats not the point, I want to learn some basic CSS :-)

Comment: from your code above you're missing a second (dot) on the vc_custom

Comment: @Aaron I tried that too, but to no avail :(

Comment: Sounds like you have some other more specific style overriding it, can you show the selector for the margin bottom that isn't crossed out when you inspect the element

Answer (score 0):

```
.vc_column-inner.vc_custom_1453133443161 {margin-bottom: 15px;}
```

You're missing the second (dot) on the vc_custom, this is a separate class.
When you're targeting an element with multiple classes each class should proceed directly after one another

`.vc_column-inner.vc_custom_1453133443161`

No space between the classes or you'll be targeting another element.

Answer (score 0):

Open up wordpress admin area. Then navigate to appearance >> editor. Then select the theme on the top right. This will list all the files, you will have to find the css files and add the statement you have to it. Use

```
.vc_column-inner{margin-bottom:15px!important}
```

Remember to check the results in your browser and inspect element. You would have to alter it accordingly if it does not work.

Comment: The OP probably has multiple `.vc_column-inner` classes and `!important` is not the best property to use

Comment: Then I would suggest using the css below from @Aaron as that is referring to that specific element